# None of my css refs work - this includes both external and internal css - always receive 404 error

Tags: css, ref

I keep getting 404 errors for both the internal files and the external files every time I try to load the corresponding website in my browser.

I have this as my code:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href='anoceanofsky.css'/>`

I have tried clearing my cache and using it on multiple browsers. The css file is definitely within the same directory as the file that this  tag is in. I also have a problem using internal css because the file is unable to load jpgs or other gif files.

e.g.

```
body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: left;
        font-family:"Adobe Garamond Pro Bold", Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        font-size: 13px;
        color: #061C37;
        background: #014D5D url(background.png);
        background-repeat:repeat-x;
      }
```

In the code above, the background.png file, which is in the same directory as the html file, doesn't load.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an absolute path instead of a relative one?

e.g.

```
body {
     background: #014D5D url(http://website.com/file/background.png);
  }
```

instead of using

```
body {
     background: #014D5D url(background.png);
  }
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but I want to be able to use a local reference.